# Watch for changes of a Moose attribute

Tags: perl, moose

Is there any way in Moose of triggering a callback when the content of an attribute is changed via reference instead of setting its value via mutator?

Let's assume the following code:

```
has _changed  => ( is => 'rw' , isa=>'Bool' ) ;
has attribute => ( 
    is=>'rw', isa=>'Maybe[HashRef]', 
    default => sub { { a => 1 , b => 2 } },     
    trigger => sub { shift->_changed(1) } 
) ;
```

the trigger works as expected setting the attribute value through mutator:

```
$self->attribute({ a => 2 , b => 2 }) ; # OK
```

but setting directly a value through its key then the trigger doesn't fires (of course):

```
$self->attribute->{a} = 3 ; # KO
```

I discarded the idea of creating (and comparing) a digest of serialized attribute's content, because it can be a very huge hashref with several nesting levels, and making a digest at every attribute access can produce a performance issue.

A tied hashref (as attribute value) could be a possible solution?
Any idea or suggestion is very appreciated.

NOTE: The structure of contained hashref is not known (I'm writing an ORM class, so the struct can vary depending on documents stored on NOSQL db side).

Comment: If you need to use the syntax `$self->attribute->{a} = ???` to update a hash key, I think a tied hash is the only(?) option. If however you could change syntax to `$self->attribute( <args> )` where `<args>` can be either a hash ref or a scalar, where `attribute` is now a method (not an attribute) and the old `attribute` is renamed to e.g. `_attribute`, you could avoid using a tied hash. Now the method `attribute` will check if its argument is a scalar or a hash ref and update `_attribute` accordingly.

Comment: @Håkon I absolutly avoid to access attributes via internal reference, but I'm developing a class will be used by other people, and I concerned on how to make it robust, because I'm quite sure that some developer will use shortcuts  even if is not a best practice :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you change the hash ref directly rather than using accessor methods, Moose is no longer involved. Having your attributes return a reference to a tied hash would be the only strategy to make changes to the hash observable, yet this is not a particularly attractive solution. Tied variables are rare and likely to trigger bugs in some code. They are comparatively difficult to implement. And they imply a performance overhead for every hash access.

Strongly consider whether you can change your design to avoid exposing the internal hash. E.g. have a getter that only returns a (shallow) copy of the hash, and a setter for individual elements in the hash. You may be able to autogenerate some of these accessors using the `handles` and `traits` mechanisms, e.g. see  [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Hash).

Comment: Or simply use an object instead of hash

Comment: Can an overload of the copy constructor (=) be a possible solution for watching a variable (of any type) for changes?

Comment: @Hannibal According to the [overload](https://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) documentation: “Simple assignment is not overloadable”. You'd have to use tied scalars for that. I don't think the “copy constructor” can help here.

Comment: @Hannibal, Re "*Can an overload of the copy constructor"*, No. Copy constructor overloads are used to create immutable objects. Magic variables (of which tied variables is one type) would be the generic approach.

Comment: Great @ikegami , you solved my day!!!!!! 
..after many years of Perl programming, that language never ends to astonish me.. MAGIC VARIABLES are the solution!!!

Comment: Well, I did some try with magic vars, but the scalar context propagation with a syntax like `sub()->{a}->{b}` forces the `store` event to fire even if there is no (explicit) assignment. A tied (recursive) interface seems the only way for achieving my goal.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach, based on [Tie::Trace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Trace) Perl module, demonstrates how to easily watch for a Moose attribute change, even if modified through a direct access to the contained hashref instead of using the appropriate setter method.

```
package Test::Document ;

use Mouse ;
use Tie::Trace qw<watch> ;

has _changed => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Bool' ) ;
...
has value => (
    is      => 'rw', isa => 'HashRef',
    default => sub { { } },
    trigger => sub { shift->_changed( 1 )  }
) ;

sub BUILD {
    my ( $self ) = @_ ;
    $self->_changed( 0 ) ; # reset flag
    watch %{ $self->{ value } } , debug=> sub {
        $self->_changed(1)
    };
    return $self ;
}

package main ;

my $doc = Test::Document->new( value => { a => 1 , b => { c => 3 } } ) ;

my $x = $doc->value->{ b }->{ e } ; # not changed

$doc->value->{ b }->{ e } = 4 ; # changed

$doc->_changed(0);
delete $doc->value->{ b }->{ e } ; # changed

$doc->_changed(0);
$doc->value({ a => 1 }) ; # changed
```

PROS: It works :)

CONS: The recursive tied approach, on hashes with a lot of keys and nesting levels, may produce performance issues. I have to do some benchmark.

NOTE: I tried with the magic vars, but the scalar context propagation with a syntax like `sub()->{a}->{b}` forces the `store` event to fire even if there is no (explicit) assignment. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hmm. It shouldn't since nothing is being stored. Will investigate when I'm no longer loafinated (have a loaf of cat on me).

Comment: It's still triggering for `my $x = $doc->value->{ b }->{ c };`